# Перевести SQL в LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Есть таблица Users, есть таблица Roles. Между ними таблица UserRoles, в которой связываются ID обеих сущностей. Мне нужно по ID пользователя получить из связующей таблицы ID соответствующей роли, а затем из таблицы ролей взять имя роли по ID.

```
SELECT r.Name FROM Roles r
JOIN UserRoles ur ON r.Id = ur.RoleId
JOIN Users u ON ur.UserId = u.Id
WHERE u.Id = "ID исходного пользователя"
```

По моим предположениям на SQL это выглядело бы так, но мне это нужно на LINQ и с точечной нотацией. Времени мало, второй день сижу. Вникнуть быстро не удаётся в LINQ при том, что SQL тоже страдает у меня, не представляю, как перевести, поэтому прошу помощи, хотя бы теоретической

Comment: Это делается через навигационное свойство. Запрос не нужен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется такой вид запрос выглядел бы более логичным :

```
       var result = from u in Users
                    join r in Roles on u.RoleId equals r.Id
                    select new {Name = u.Name,RoleName = r.RoleName}
```

И приведу пример построение класса ,чтобы данный запрос вернул адекватные значения

```
  public class User
  {
   public string Name {get;set;}
    //другая важная информация о пользователях
   public int RoleId {get;set;}
   public Role Role {get;set;}
  }      
  public class Roles
  {
   public string Id{get;set;}
   public string RoleName{get;set;}
  }
```

Ещё пример как наш запрос будет выглядеть на T-SQL :

```
select Users.Name , Roles.RoleName 
from Users 
join Roles on Users.RoleId = Roles.Id
```

И тут мы вполне можем обойтись без таблицы `UserRoles` - которую мы по-сути формируем из нашего запроса )

**UPD:** : обновим наши два класса `User` и `Roles` так ,чтобы `User` мог иметь  несколько ролей .

Класс `User` :

```
public class User
  {
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    //другая важная информация о пользователях
    public ICollection<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
    public User()
    {
        Roles = new List<Roles>();
    }
  }
```

Касс `Roles` :

```
    public class Roles
  {
   public string Id{get;set;}
   public string RoleName{get;set;}
   public int? UserId { get; set; }
   public User User { get; set; } 
  }
```

*Пример работы :*

```
 User u1 = new User {Name =" Test1"};
 Roles user = new Roles {RoleName ="User",User = u1};
 Roles admin = new Roles {RoleName ="Admin" ,User = u1};
 //вывод
 var test_result = from u in Users
                join r in Roles on u.RoleId equals r.Id
                select new {Name = u.Name,RoleName = r.RoleName}

 foreach (var p in result)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - ({1})", p.Name, p.RoleName);
```

Comment: "И тут мы вполне можем обойтись без таблицы UserRoles" - только пока у пользователя одна роль.

Comment: @Zufir обновил ответ - теперь можно добавлять несколько ролей к юзеру

Comment: Наименование в качестве ключа? Ну, допустимо, конечно, но в конце этого пути обычно лежит большая поляна, усыпанная граблями и ружьями для стрельбы в ногу.

Comment: @Zufir я просто привел один из вариантов как можно сделать - очень хотелось бы услышать как избежать этих проблем,поскольку я относительно недавно начал изучать фреймворк